# Superfluous tag: [aspnet-identity]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, retag-request

The [aspnet-identity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/aspnet-identity) (102 Q's) is superfluous as there is a non-misspelled tag [asp.net-identity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/asp.net-identity) (2346 Q's)which has more questions.

Comment: You could suggest a synonym http://stackoverflow.com/tags/asp.net-identity/synonyms

Comment: @MartinSmith It seems cleaner to me to retag the few questions using the misspelled tag. If it was more than just these few ones that would probably be the right way to do it.

Comment: @LJNielsenDk it might be an idea to merge aspnet-identity into asp.net-identity and leave a syn to prevent future typos and allow auto remapping. That'll effectively be a re-tag and prevent re-introducing the tag in the future. That can be done via the system instead of manually re-tagging. Unless you can think of a reason a syn. isn't suitable?

Comment: @JonClements Good point.

Answer (score 11):

[aspnet-identity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/aspnet-identity) is merged and syn'd to [asp.net-identity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/asp.net-identity)

Answer (score 6):

(I do not know if that specifies as an answer ...)

There are more with this scheme which are misspelled:

```
misspelled                                         alternative
-------------------------------------------------- -------------------------------------------------------------
aspnet-compiler × 124 (18 asked this year)         asp.net-compiler × 10       
aspnetdb × 107 (8 asked this year)
aspnet-regiis.exe × 60 (12 asked this year) 
aspnet-identity × 52 (58 asked this year)          asp.net-identity × 2391 31 asked this week, 92 this month 
                                                   asp.net-identity-2 × 631 7 asked this week, 28 this month
                                                   asp.net-identity-3 × 23 7 asked  this month
aspnet-development-server× 23 (6 asked this year)  asp.net-development-serv × 59 
aspnet-merge × 13 (1 asked this year)
asp-net-mvc-1 × 5 (4 asked this year)              asp.net-mvc × 116049 53 asked today, 587 this week
                                                   asp.net-mvc-3 × 38277 28 asked this week, 73 this month
                                                   asp.net-mvc-4 × 33738 17 asked today, 187 this week
                                                   asp.net-mvc-2 × 8643 7 asked this month, 73 this year
                                                   asp.net-mvc-5 × 7217 5 asked today, 86 this week
                                                   asp.net-mvc-routing × 3147 11 asked this week, 44 this month
aspnet-websocket 
aspnet.mvc
```