# Suggested Edit review without any difference

Tags: discussion, review-queues

In this review https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/9259254 there is no visible difference.

The comment of the suggested edit says "Comment: Retag with correctly spelled asp.net-identity tag.", but this seems already tagged as [asp.net-identity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/asp.net-identity).

I just see a second case, https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/9259092, from the same [user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1514681/ljnielsendk).

I rejected the first one, and hesitated with the second one. Perhaps I will skip this review.

What's your opinion on such a situation?

Comment: I think you will find that this is related to the discussion here: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303203/superfluous-tag-aspnet-identity

Comment: Possibly related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/231328/a-suggested-edit-was-submitted-without-any-changes

Comment: @BrianTompsett-汤莱恩 Does It means the edit was done before the 2 tags [tag:asp.net-identity] and [tag:aspnet-identity] where merged ?

Comment: @mpromonet They were, and this is probably why, but I'm not sure.

Comment: @LJNielsenDk as you post the meta question and the suggested-edits it seems more than probable, it is just confusing to review this suggestion because nothing indicate the tag you remove and the tag you add were merged. Then these suggested editions doesnot change anything.

Comment: @pnuts then, you suggest to approve the suggested-edit to keep the comment ?